# Ul table like in css

Tags: css, html-lists

I am suffering from creating nice menus with ul and li items. e.g. when I have only 4 item menu I give them same width 20% and it never breaks, same it works even for 6 item menu I give them 16,66666% width which CSS supports. But now there is a problem, this works only for items which can have same width, what I am looking for is solution for different width items and there is a condition, container must be every time 100% or 1000px (simply full width) and li´s cannot overflow container and container must be centered like:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
     <li>Item1</li>
     <li>Longnameitem 2</li>
     <li>it3</li>
     <li>SuperlongnameItem 4</li>
     <li>Item5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Normally my CSS would be like:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 30px;
}
.container ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
.container ul li {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

This works fine, but I need dynamic width for each li "table like", any ideas? tricks? table-cell CSS tricks? or other? (If there is a mistake, ignore it, I just typed it for example)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fUatw/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into **'flexbox'**

First **[Check here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)** for it's browser support.

**[Here is an example with your code menu (ul/li) code using flexbox](http://jsfiddle.net/GTUn8/)**

---

The setup

**CSS**

```
    .grid {
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
    }
    .col {
       background: #ccc;
      padding: 30px;
    }
    .fluid {
        flex: 1;
    }
   .fixed {
     background: red;
     width: 400px;
    }
```

**MARKUP**

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col fluid"> ...</div>
  <div class="col fixed"> ...</div>
  <div class="col fluid"> ...</div>
</div>
```

Notice how we can set paddings on these 'layout' elements and it's ok, notice how we don't have to 'clear' floats. Great Stuff.

There is a fab [example here](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/qazmI) by Chris Coyier of CSS Tricks where the above snippet was taken from.

---

Answer (score 0):

**CSS Dynamic widths control using LESS Mixins for UL's and LI's**

1. Firsty, review the steps in this article: [CSS Intro to LESS Mixins](http://www.sitepoint.com/a-comprehensive-introduction-to-less-mixins/)
2. Create CSS Classes, associated Properties, and ID Rulesets for your UL's and LI's
3. Test passing multiple Arguments to modify your UL's and LI's with different dynamic widths
4. Test using Guards and apply conditions to tailor how LESS Mixin's are used whilst maintaining your container's full width, centering, and preventing overflow
5. Test using Operators and LESS to achieve desired proportions between stylesheet elements

Was this helpful? If you follow-through with this LESS Mixin approach to CSS refactoring then in the long-run you'll hopefully have fun making menus! Please give me some feedback and let me know how you go!